# Caused a HMError when running HTKDemo

Tags: htk

I just installed HTS-2.2 and HTK-3.4.1 in my 64bit Ubuntu with gcc 3.4 compiler. After that, typing HInit and HCopy etc. seemed work. So I wondered how the HTKDemo works.

When I run the demo, HTK caused a problem:

```
HMM Def Error: <Mean> symbol expected in GetMean at line 6/col 11/char 120 in proto/L
  ERROR [+7050]  HMError:
HMM Def Error: GetMean Failed at line 6/col 12/char 121 in proto/L
  ERROR [+7050]  HMError:
HMM Def Error: Regression Class Number expected at line 7/col 0/char 122 in proto/L
  ERROR [+7050]  HMError:
HMM Def Error: GetMixtures failed at line 7/col 1/char 123 in proto/L
  ERROR [+7050]  HMError:
HMM Def Error: Get Stream Information failed at line 7/col 2/char 124 in proto/L
  ERROR [+7050]  HMError:
HMM Def Error: GetStream failed at line 7/col 3/char 125 in proto/L
  ERROR [+7050]  HMError:
HMM Def Error: GetStateInfo failed at line 7/col 4/char 126 in proto/L
  ERROR [+7050]  HMError:
  ERROR [+7032]  LoadHMMSet: GetHMMDef failed
  ERROR [+2128]  Initialise: LoadHMMSet failed
 FATAL ERROR - Terminating program HInit
Source Directory Empty hmms/hmm.0
```

The same to the proto S, V, N, C.

I really want to know the reason and how to fix it? Thx!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same +7050 error, in my case was a mispelled hmm definition file, probably you have the same problem since the error reported: " symbol expected".
Just check your definition file had the right format as follows:

```
~h (phoneme name)
<BEGINHMM>
<NUMSTATES> (NStates)
<STATE> 2 (number starting from 2, ending NStates-1 )
<MEAN> 13 (or any number defined)
 -4.717658e+000 ... 
<VARIANCE> 13 (the same as mean possibly)
 4.735534e+001 ...
<STATE> 3 ....
...
<GCONST> 1.269744e+002
<TRANSP> 3 (again not important)
 0.0 1.0 0.0
 0.0 0.9 0.1
 0.0 0.0 0.0
<ENDHMM>
~h (next phoneme )
...
```

Comment: I hava found the reason. It's just because the source code HTKDemo given is wrong.